# Using Feature Model as basis for Ontology?

Tags: data-structures, ontology

I have understood that there is no universal concept to create an ontology. However, a visualization is required to share the ideas. Are there any presentation methods that are allowed / desired and which are forbidden? As far as i know is a logical representation the way to go but this isn't really handy to explain like graphs for example.

I have found that my data structure can be perfectly explained with the "feature model". It includes the needed Semantics like "alternative, or, mandatory". But I am unsure to use it as a basis for the ontology.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research i realized there are two different categories to visualize the knowledge of an ontology:

First an visual representation model - more likely to used **for humans** (UML, Mindmap, ...)

Second a detailed representation model (ontology-description-language) - **for humans and machines** (OWL, RDFS, ...)

When you want to explain your model to other humans you really have the choice of all the existing representation models that exist. The "Feature Model" I suggested in the question would be suitable as far as I understood. You could also create your really own representation that fits your needs. But you need to define rules and create a crystal clear understanding how to read your representation so that other people can understand. This human readable schematic is a good starting point to dig deeper and describe the model in an ontology-description-language.